# Why is rails adding weird fragments to my urls?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I noticed that rails is now adding weird fragments to my urls. For example:

`mysite.com/controller/action`

becomes

`mysite.com/controller/action#.Uq14P_QW2oM`

What's the story behind this, and how to prevent it?

Comment: This looks the footprint of AddThis. Do you have AddThis installed?

Comment: I do. Wow, that's interesting. Any way to avoid that (besides removing AddThis)?

Comment: That's AddThis's tracking id. If somebody shared a link from AddThis, and others followed his sharing, AddThis could log it as response according to the tracking code, and measure the effectiveness. I forget how to disable it, it seems you can do that in AddThis Dashboard or when embbding the code and add option, you can check their doc for details Anyway it doesn't hurt too much if you want to track them.

Comment: I did not find the other questions, but this is coming up every once and a while on SO :)

Comment: @BillyChan, you had the right answer, maybe you can write it up? :)